# Vagrant unidirectional synced folder

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have been using synced folders in Vagrant for a while, but the behaviour is not what I expected. It seems both changes in the host machines and changes in the guest machine are synced. However, I want syncing to be in only one direction: from the host to the guest. Part of the reason I want to create a Vagrant machine is that, if my code accidentally does something destructive, like deleting itself, I want that behaviour to be contained in a safe environment.

For reference, this is the Vagrantfile I am using:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8080, guest: 80
  config.vm.synced_folder "test", "/test", :nfs => true
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

where bootstrap.h just executes `apt-get install nfs-common portmap`.

**What is the easiest way I can configure unidirectional syncing in Vagrant?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Vagrant 1.5 you can use `rsync` as sync folder method:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder "test", "/test", type: "rsync",
end
```

This is unidirectional.